# HTML title is looking different in Firefox browser

Tags: html, css

I am using a normal title to show tooltips on my website. I don't want to use any other tooltips on my page. I need a simple default browser title.

But in Firefox browser the title looks different. Not in all cases, just in some scenarios .

Here is the Fiddle [**Title Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hzqh3y3/)

```js
$('.ACName').each(function() {
    var $ele = $(this);
    if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth)
        $ele.attr('title', $ele.text());
});
```

```css
.myProspectTable{
    width:463px;
    border:1px solid #a3a3a3;
}
.myProspectTable tr td{
    border-left:1px solid #a3a3a3;
    padding:5px;
}
.myProspectTable tr td:nth-child(1) div{
    width:160px;
   white-space: nowrap;
     overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myProspectTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="ACName text-decoration-none">
     <span style="border-left: 3px solid #2BF300; margin-right: 5px;"></span>
                    <span style="font-weight: bold;">(AMSI) ADVANCE MACHINE &amp; TRETCHFORM INTERNATIONAL INC.</span>
   </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:100px;">
            XXXXXXXX
        </td>
        <td style="width:100px;">
            123456
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For more details please see below Image.
[image]

help me resolve this

Comment: can you create a fiddle, it will be more clear.

Comment: @MohamedWazil: Please see my attached code. I edit the Question with code and Fiddle [This is the Link for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hzqh3y3/)

Comment: @Kaiido: Please see my attached code. I edit the Question with code and Fiddle [This is the Link for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hzqh3y3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Title attribute respects whitespaces, however apparently browsers handle them a little differently. In you case you want to trim unwanted trailing and leading whitespace characters to achieve consistent look.

Try to use [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

```
$ele.attr('title', $ele.text().trim());
```

or [$.trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) if you want to support IE8 and below:

```
$ele.attr('title', $.trim($ele.text()));
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ajLn421s/1/